# Filters in the url are ovewritten by default state of the Security events Dashboard in Wazuh Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, opensearch-dashboards, wazuh

I have a table in my Opensearch Dashboard. Also, I have Dashboard in Wazuh, integrated in Elastic. Wazuh is like a security application with its built-in dashboards of different categories.

I need to create an url for the table field: agent.name. It has to be redirected to that dashboard in Wazuh with configured filters. When I click the field value it redirects to Wazuh, where a Health check is performed first before accessing the Wazuh dashboard. In that stage, all filters are reset to the default of Wazuh. It means that my desired filters are changed and not applied to the dashboard.

Is there any way to keep filters or escape the health check stage?

I could not really find a way to disable Health Check entirely. In the  Settings < Configuration of Wazuh I could disable some fields like `checks.pattern` and `checks.template`. Not sure if it could be the cause of my problem.

I would appreciate any help